# How to traverse the array in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

while pushing the object into the array , the value is not pushed correctly.
Please give me the solution for following code.

```
finalarr: Array<any> = [];
All: { [k: string]: any } = [];

this.All = {
 typeid: 1,
 description: "just test"
}

this.finalarr.push(this.All);
```

Output:
Actual result:[image: this is just an format of array, values will be changed]

Expected result:
[image: this is just an format of array, values will be changed]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I find it very unlikely the code snippet you provided produces your actual result.

Comment: the image was just an format of output, the values are sample and i was not able to describe the exact output without image.

Comment: Your code and output do not correspond to each other. Please provide proper output.